# IOS Bluetooth Low Energy Notifications - Objective-C Code Works with Some Devices and Not Others

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've put together some pretty basic iOS Objective-C code for Bluetooth BLE intended to connect and get notifications from a custom peripheral device. The custom device updates the characteristic value 1x per second.

The callback method does not (seem to) fire when the characteristic value is updated:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
```

This is in spite of the fact that the characteristic has  setNotifyValue:YES per below code fragment:

```
if([aChar.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:MW_DEVICE_BREATH_DATA4_CHAR_UUID]])
    [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:aChar];
```

The custom peripheral device works perfectly fine on LightBlue on the Mac as well as LightBlue Explorer on the iPhone; notifications are received and the correct value updates are displayed.

Furthermore, and most confusingly, the same exact code works fine for a Heart Rate Monitor peripheral when just the service and characteristic UUIDs are changed.  The callback gets fired and the characteristic value is updated.

This question seems to very similar to :

1) [iOS Bluetooth LE cant get notification programatically but can in other apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322746/ios-bluetooth-le-cant-get-notification-programatically-but-can-in-other-apps)
2) [Bluetooth LE notifications not received on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29341435/bluetooth-le-notifications-not-received-on-ios)
3) [How to get notification from Bluetooth LE devices in iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858096/how-to-get-notification-from-bluetooth-le-devices-in-ios-app)

Per question 1) above, I do have the delegate set.  There weren't answers for 2) or 3) that seemed relevant.

I admit that I'm a bit confused about the persistence of "peripheral".  I've created a property mwDvcPeripheral and used explicit references to it in the various function parameters; it doesn't seem to have an effect positive or negative.

Is this a subtle timing issue involving 128bit UUIDs? What is LightBlue doing that I am not?

I have a feeling that the answer to this is so obvious that I'll need to kick myself when it is pointed out.

Here is the Objective-C header file:
    //
    //  ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@import CoreBluetooth;

#define MW_DEVICE_INFO_SVC_UUID @"180a"
#define MW_MFG_NAME_CHAR_UUID  @"2A29"

// Heart Rate Monitor ***** Use these UUIDs instead of below and everything works ******
//#define MW_DEVICE_MET_SVC_UUID @"180d"
//#define MW_DEVICE_BREATH_DATA4_CHAR_UUID @"2a37"

// MetWear Custom Device
#define MW_DEVICE_MET_SVC_UUID @"11223344-5566-7788-9900-aabbccddeeff"
#define MW_DEVICE_BREATH_DATA4_CHAR_UUID @"01020304-0506-0708-0900-0a0b0c0d0e0f"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) CBCentralManager *centralManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CBPeripheral *mwDvcPeripheral;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextView *deviceInfo;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *mwData4Characteristic;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *connected;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *mfgr;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *metWearDvcData;


-(void)getMWData4Characteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic;
-(void)getMfgNameCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic;

@end
```

Here is the Objective-C code stripped of most non-essentials:
    //
    // ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.metWearDvcData = nil;
    [self.deviceInfo setText:@""];
    [self.deviceInfo setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];   // keep keyboard from popping up.
    CBCentralManager *centralManager = [[CBCentralManager     alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
    self.centralManager = centralManager;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - CBCentralManagerDelegate

// method called whenever a connection has been established.
-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
    [peripheral setDelegate:self];
    [peripheral discoverServices:nil];
    self.connected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connected: %@", peripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected ? @"YES" : @"NO"];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.connected);
}

// CBCentralManagerDelegate - This is called with the CBPeripheral class as its main input parameter.  This contains most of the information there is to know about a BLE peripheral.
-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSString *localName = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey];
    if([localName length] > 0 ){
        NSLog(@"Found MetWear Device: %@", localName);
        [self.centralManager stopScan];
        self.mwDvcPeripheral = peripheral;
        peripheral.delegate = self;
        [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
    }
}

// method called whenever the device state changes
-(void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    if([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff){
    NSLog(@"Core Bluetooth BLE hardware powered off");
    }
    else if([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn){
        NSLog(@"Core Bluetooth BLE hardware powered on and ready");
        NSArray *services = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:MW_DEVICE_INFO_SVC_UUID],[CBUUID UUIDWithString:MW_DEVICE_MET_SVC_UUID]];
        [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:services options:nil];
    }
    else if([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized){
        NSLog(@"Core Bluetooth BLE state is unauthorized");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnknown){
        NSLog(@"Core Bluetooth BLE state is unknown");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported){
        NSLog(@"Core Bluetooth BLE state is unsupported");
    }
}

#pragma mark - CBPeripheralDelegate 

// CBPeripheralDelegate - Invoked when you discover the peripheral's available services
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{
    for(CBService *service in peripheral.services){
        NSLog(@"Discovered Service: %@", service.UUID);
        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];
    }
}

// Invoked when you discover characteristics of the spec'd service
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{
    if([service.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:MW_DEVICE_MET_SVC_UUID]]){
        for(CBCharacteristic *aChar in service.characteristics) {
            if([aChar.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:MW_DEVICE_BREATH_DATA4_CHAR_UUID]]){
                [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:aChar];
                NSLog(@"Discovered MetWear Data4 Characteristic: %@", aChar);
                [self getMWData4Characteristic:aChar];

            }
        }
    }
    if([service.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:MW_DEVICE_INFO_SVC_UUID]]){
        for(CBCharacteristic *aChar in service.characteristics) {
            [peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:aChar];
            NSLog(@"Discovered MetWear mfgr name Characteristic: %@", aChar);
        }
    }
}

// Invoked when a spec'd characteristic's state changes
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateStateForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Peripheral State Changed");
}

// Invoked when you retrieve a spec'd characteristic's value, or when the peripheral device notifies the app that the characteristic's value has changed
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    if([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:MW_DEVICE_BREATH_DATA4_CHAR_UUID]]){
        [self getMWData4Characteristic:characteristic];
        NSLog(@"Data4 Characteristic is: %@", characteristic);
    }
    if([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:MW_MFG_NAME_CHAR_UUID]]){
        [self getMfgNameCharacteristic:characteristic];
        NSLog(@"Mfgr is: %@", characteristic);
    }
}

// Characteristic helpers

- (void)getMWData4Characteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic {
     NSLog(@"Data4: %@", [characteristic value]);
}

- (void)getMfgNameCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic {
     NSString *mfgrName = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     self.deviceInfo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n", self.connected, mfgrName];
}

@end
```

Lastly, here is the Console Output associated with the output for the above code:

```
2016-07-31 21:01:26.042 MetWear[551:99182] Core Bluetooth BLE hardware powered on and ready
2016-07-31 21:01:26.256 MetWear[551:99182] Found MetWear Device: METWR1
2016-07-31 21:01:26.421 MetWear[551:99182] Connected: YES
2016-07-31 21:01:26.488 MetWear[551:99182] Discovered Service: Device Information
2016-07-31 21:01:26.488 MetWear[551:99182] Discovered Service: 11223344-5566-7788-9900-AABBCCDDEEFF
2016-07-31 21:01:26.489 MetWear[551:99182] Discovered Service: Battery
2016-07-31 21:01:26.493 MetWear[551:99182] Discovered MetWear mfgr name Characteristic: <CBCharacteristic: 0x17e39f20, UUID = Serial Number String, properties = 0x2, value = <31323334>, notifying = NO>
2016-07-31 21:01:26.493 MetWear[551:99182] Discovered MetWear mfgr name Characteristic: <CBCharacteristic: 0x17e3a040, UUID = Hardware Revision String, properties = 0x2, value = <312e30>, notifying = NO>
2016-07-31 21:01:26.494 MetWear[551:99182] Discovered MetWear mfgr name Characteristic: <CBCharacteristic: 0x17e3a120, UUID = Firmware Revision String, properties = 0x2, value = <312e30>, notifying = NO>
2016-07-31 21:01:26.494 MetWear[551:99182] Discovered MetWear mfgr name Characteristic: <CBCharacteristic: 0x17e3a160, UUID = Software Revision String, properties = 0x2, value = <312e30>, notifying = NO>
2016-07-31 21:01:26.494 MetWear[551:99182] Discovered MetWear mfgr name Characteristic: <CBCharacteristic: 0x17e3a1a0, UUID = Manufacturer Name String, properties = 0x2, value = <4a617276 6973204c 616273>, notifying = NO>
2016-07-31 21:01:26.495 MetWear[551:99182] Discovered MetWear mfgr name Characteristic: <CBCharacteristic: 0x17e3a0c0, UUID = Model Number String, properties = 0x2, value = <4d657457 6561724f 6e65>, notifying = NO>
2016-07-31 21:01:26.496 MetWear[551:99182] Discovered MetWear Data4 Characteristic: <CBCharacteristic: 0x17d3cee0, UUID = 01020304-0506-0708-0900-0A0B0C0D0E0F, properties = 0x12, value = (null), notifying = NO>
2016-07-31 21:01:26.496 MetWear[551:99182] Data4: (null)
2016-07-31 21:01:26.793 MetWear[551:99182] Mfgr is: <CBCharacteristic: 0x17e3a1a0, UUID = Manufacturer Name String, properties = 0x2, value = <4a617276 6973204c 616273>, notifying = NO>
```

I have been successful in getting this code working; only with brute force however.  I found that a (long) delay using a "for loop" added after:
    [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
was successful.

I'm a bit confused as to why this is effective and needed in the first place.  I'm supposing that there is a synchronization issue with the call back or a subtle timing issue with the RN4020 BLE module but that is only a guess.  I certainly have some more exploring to do.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you move your bluetooth code out of the view  controller and put it in its own class.  Either implement this class as a singleton or hold a reference on your AppDelegate.  This class can then use delegation or NSNotification to advise the view controller of updates

Comment: I agree with @Paulw11 's comment

Comment: Thanks for the reply. FWIW, I was using a code template that I found on a tutorial website. The code works with other devices so I didn't want to add another variable to the situation. I will ultimately follow your advice. @BasanthVerma

Comment: This issue was finally resolved!!!  The problem was a subtle issue with the RN4020 Bluetooth module configuration.  In particular, the "Server Only" bit needed to be set in the configuration profile.